# Which model to choose for interactive effects within groups in SPSS

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multiple-regression

I have 4 diet groups (ST, MSG, TFA, MSG+TFA) and the cholesterol levels were checked at 20wk, 32wk and 40wk. From the raw data it is quite clear that MSG+TFA group had high values of cholesterol compared to MSG and TFA taken singly. What I am interested in is whether the higher levels of cholesterol in MSG+TFA group is because of additive or interactive effect i.e. cholesterol level is high because of MSG and TFA acted independently or MSG interacted with TFA to give the high value.

For this which model should I use in SPSS? I only have basic knowledge of statistics. Is it multiple linear regression? Or repeated measures ANOVA? And in the output where do you know whether the effect is interactive?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site!

You want some form of model that accounts for the dependent nature of the data; this could be repeated measures ANOVA or a multilevel model or generalized estimating equations. All these have been discussed a lot here. Searching using the 'longitudinal` tag will find a lot of threads.

You can tell if the effects are purely additive by comparing the effect sizes for the different groups.

If you need help with SPSS specifically, then the question should move to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response...Yes I need help with SPSS specifically. I did alot of reading and i am getting more and more confused.. While doing analysis for interactive effect between MSG and TFA should I exclude the ST and MSG+TFA dataset and then do the model? I tried the multiple linear regression and repeated measures, but I still cant figure out where to look for the interactive effect..